# Vscode debugger importError

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I try to debug my remote django project by vscode debugger. When the program launched, the module I install in the virtualenv is not used, but the module in vscode is used. I found this by printing the module

```
import completion
print(completion)

#output
<module 'completion' from '/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.1.57204/pythonFiles/completion.pyc'>
```

but in the remote python manage.py shell:

```
import completion
print(completion)

#output
<module 'completion' from '/{my_python_path}/site-packages/completion/__init__.pyc'>
```

the launch.json is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "justMyCode": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I delete the `completion.py` in `/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.1.57204/pythonFiles/` then the program launch success...But it may break some features?
What is the completion module used for?
How to import the module from the virtualenv?

Comment: go to definition and find references are not working after removed the `completion.py` 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because that directory gets put on your `sys.path` to load the debugger. Feel free to open a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python to consider renaming the file so there's less of a chance of clashing with one of your own files.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That's the reason. I open the issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9593 and mention you